# Working with Azure Storage Emulator returns 404

Tags: php, azure

So, I've downloaded Azure SDK for php and started the emulator. Everything ok.
Then I copy&pasted code from [Microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-php-how-to-use-blobs/#create-a-php-application), so I can create a new test container.

```
require_once 'vendor\autoload.php';
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\CreateContainerOptions;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\PublicAccessType;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\ServiceException;

// Create blob REST proxy.
$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService('UseDevelopmentStorage=true');


// OPTIONAL: Set public access policy and metadata.
// Create container options object.
$createContainerOptions = new CreateContainerOptions();

// Set public access policy. Possible values are
// PublicAccessType::CONTAINER_AND_BLOBS and PublicAccessType::BLOBS_ONLY.
// CONTAINER_AND_BLOBS:
// Specifies full public read access for container and blob data.
// proxys can enumerate blobs within the container via anonymous
// request, but cannot enumerate containers within the storage account.
//
// BLOBS_ONLY:
// Specifies public read access for blobs. Blob data within this
// container can be read via anonymous request, but container data is not
// available. proxys cannot enumerate blobs within the container via
// anonymous request.
// If this value is not specified in the request, container data is
// private to the account owner.
$createContainerOptions->setPublicAccess(PublicAccessType::CONTAINER_AND_BLOBS);

// Set container metadata.
$createContainerOptions->addMetaData("key1", "value1");
$createContainerOptions->addMetaData("key2", "value2");

try {
    // Create container.
    $blobRestProxy->createContainer("mycontainer", $createContainerOptions);
} catch (ServiceException $e) {
    // Handle exception based on error codes and messages.
    // Error codes and messages are here:
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd179439.aspx
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo $code . ": " . $error_message . "<br />";
}
```

When I run this code, I get a nice error message.

> 404: Fail: 
>   Code: 404 
>   Value: The specified resource does not exist.

What's wrong with this? I'm running out of ideas. Firstly I had a slightly different code that didn't work either, so now I try to use this sample directly from MS with no luck.

CLI shows that the emulator is running and also that endpoints are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Fiddler to capture the http request generated by the SDK, the url path was `/testcontainer?restype=container`. And according the Rest API guide https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179468.aspx, the url path should be `/devstoreaccount1/mycontainer?restype=container`.

Currently, there is a workaround to develop with Azure Storage on local emulator. We can add the local account name `devstoreaccount1` every time when we use the container name, e.g.

```
$blobRestProxy->createContainer("devstoreaccount1/testcontainer");
$blobRestProxy->createBlockBlob("devstoreaccount1/testcontainer", "testblob", "test string");
$blobRestProxy->listBlobs("devstoreaccount1/testcontainer");
```

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I just wonder why this isn't documented anywhere :-/ Or did I miss it somewhere? It's obviously a big bug preventing people of using it.